# Как сделать абсолютное позиционирование логотипа, используя bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Как сделать абсолютное позиционирование логотипа, используя bootstrap?

Логотип находится в том же контейнере, что и меню навигации. Контейнер будет иметь фоновое изображение, и нужно чтобы контейнер был высотой с меню, без учета высоты логотипа.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">

        <a href="#" class="pull-left"><img src="img/Logo.png"></a> <!--Логотип -->

      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>

    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse pull-right">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Services</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Portfolio</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Blog</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А что вам мешает прописать свои стили через класс или id? Или переопределить бутсраповские? Например так:

```css
.my-logo {
  position: absolute;
}
.my-navbar {
  background-image: url("http://images.freeimages.com/images/previews/01a/technology-background-1632715.jpg");
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <nav class="my-navbar navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">

        <a href="#" class="my-logo pull-left"><img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=Logo&w=200&h=100"></a> <!--Логотип -->

      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>

    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse pull-right">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Services</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Portfolio</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Blog</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Спасибо, это то что мне нужно. Я думал нет ли для этого специального класса bootstrap.